# Can I use method hiding on an ActionResult that has the same signature as the base controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have 2 controllers, one inheriting the other. I need to override an ActionResult from the base controller because I need to change to code to implement pagination in the plugin for nopCommerce. However, I get an AmbiguousMatchException because of the new ActionResult.

Base Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Category(int categoryId, CatalogPagingFilteringModel command)
    {
        //original action result code
    }
}
```

Customer Controller w/ inheritance

```
public class CustomController : BaseController {
    public new ActionResult Category(int categoryId, CatalogPagingFilteringModel command)
    {
        // my pagination code with different model/view
    }
}
```

Route Info:
Here I remove the route for the base controller and add a new route to use the CustomCatalog controller.

```
routes.Remove(routes["OriginalCategory"]);
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
                            "OriginalCategory",
                            "Category/{categoryId}/{SeName}",
                            new { controller = "CustomCatalog", action = "Category", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
                            new { categoryId = @"\d+" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Common.Web.Controllers" });
```

I then get an AmbiguousMatchException

> [AmbiguousMatchException: The current request for action 'Category' on
>   controller type 'CustomCatalogController' is ambiguous between the
>   following action methods: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Category(Int32,
>   Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CatalogPagingFilteringModel) on type
>   Nop.Plugin.Common.Web.Controllers.CustomCatalogController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Category(Int32,
>   Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CatalogPagingFilteringModel) on type
>   Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController]

**EDIT**
The base controller resides in the core of the application where as the CustomController is in the plugin meaning that I cannot modify the base controller's type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override a method which has not been declared `virtual`.

You can either define a new method with a different signature or you can encapsulate the functionality of the original class by maintaining a private reference to it in a wrapper class.  It helps if you have an interface that you can implement from the base library (because this allows you to substitute the wrapper class where the base class that implements the same interface would be used), but you can do it without the interface, too.

```
// Base class source code is not modifiable
class BaseClass {
   public ActionResult Category(...) {}
   public ActionResult Other() {}
}

// Wrapper class can modify the behavior
class Wrapper {
  private BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();  // Instantiate appropriately

  public ActionResult Category(...) {
    // do some stuff
  }

  public ActionResult Other() {
    return baseClass.Other();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using `virtual` in the base controller and `override` in the derived controller instead of `new`?

base:

```
public virtual ActionResult Category(...) { }
```

derived:

```
public override ActionResult Category(...) { }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the type of the base ActionResult since it's part of the core and not part of the plugin.